# How to get core data distinct values with relationship values?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to get all the distinct Identity values (contact has many identities). I am also trying to get the contact.sectionIndex from the contact model. I am trying the code below and get "returned nil value for section name key path 'Contact.sectionIndex'" for each record.

```
NSFetchRequest *req = NSFetchRequestMake(@"Identity", managedObjectContext);
req.fetchBatchSize = 20;
req.sortDescriptors = NSSortDescriptors1(@"sortname", YES);
[req setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[req setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[req setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"identityID", @"sortname"]];


// Create & return the fetchedResultsController.
fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                            initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                            managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                            sectionNameKeyPath:@"contact.sectionIndex" cacheName:nil];
[VenmoUtilities performFetch:fetchedResultsController critical:NO];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property used as `sectionNameKeyPath` must be included in the `propertiesToFetch`:

```
[req setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"identityID", @"sortname", @"contact.sectionIndex"]];
```

Comment: when I do that I get "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 contact]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: so it works, but I want the results to be unique only on identityID. The new properties are  [req setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"identityID", @"sortname", @"contact.sectionIndex", @"contact.name]];

Effectively I do not want duplicate identityID values, regardless of whether or not the contact name is the same. Right now its getting unique identityID values but only for each contact. I want it so that if there are contacts with different names, but same identityID it will only return one. Make sense?

Comment: @angrymonkey: I don't think that is possible with a Core Data fetch request. If you fetch 4 properties (p1, p2, p3, p4) then with the "distinct results" option, then you get one object for each unique value of that 4-tuple of properties.

Comment: yeah thats what I figured. Is there any way I can make the contact a subentity and do it like that or does it seem like thats not possible?

Comment: @angrymonkey: Why do you include "contact.name" in propertiesToFetch? Then you get different objects for different names.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32592/discussion-between-angrymonkey-and-martin-r)

Comment: @angrymonkey: Any news on this problem? I am sorry if the answer did not really help, but I do not have more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple doc you can see you may asking too much from the request.

Discussion

The property descriptions may represent attributes, to-one relationships, or expressions. The name of an attribute or relationship description must match the name of a description on the fetch request’s entity.